# Find title of checked label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Got a bit of a tricky one and wondered if anyone had a suggestion.

So I've written a script that finds any labels that have a class of selected on their parent, it'll clone them and append them to an active list so that I am creating a 'Filtered Items' list.

What I want to do is find the title of each section that the label belongs to and append this to each label, so if it's been selected from the 'Size' section I'd like the active label to read 'Size: S' and if it's come from the 'Colour' section to read 'Colour: Blue'. Currently, I've only managed to get it so it spits out all the titles but can't scope it down to the correct filter section.

```js
var filterItem = '.m-refinement-item',
  filterItemClick = filterItem + ' .js-button-apply';

function swipeyFilterBtns() {
  $(".content-stuff").before("<section class='swipeySizeFilter'></section>");

  var index = 1;
  var text_val = $('.m-refinement-item').find('.js-refinement-name').text();

  console.log(text_val);

  $(filterItem)
    .find('.selected label')
    .clone()
    .wrapInner('<span class="swipeyLabelText">' + text_val + ': </span>')
    .appendTo($('.swipeySizeFilter'));

  $('.swipeySizeFilter label').each(function() {
    $(this)
      .addClass('swipeyFilterLabel')
      .attr('data-position', index);
    index++;
  });
}

function swipeyFilterClicky() {
  $(".swipeyFilterLabel").click(
    function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(".js-overlay.js-mobile-overlay.m-refine-by-button").click();
        $(filterItemClick).click();
        $(".js-apply-refinements").click();
      }, 400);
    });
}

function swipeyFilterActiveItems() {
  $('.input-checkbox').on('change', function() {
    $(this).add('label[for="' + this.id + '"]').toggleClass('NickTester').toggleClass('swipeyFilterBtnActive', this.checked);
  }).trigger('change');
}

function swipeyFilterSetup() {
  var swipeyFilterCheck = $('.swipeyWrapper');

  if (swipeyFilterCheck.length === 0) {
    $('.swipeyFilterLabel').wrapAll('<div class="swipeyWrapper"><div class="swipeyContainer"></div></div>');
    $('<span class="swipeyFilterActiveList"></span>').prependTo('.swipeyContainer');
    $('<div class="swipeyFilterOverlay"></div>').prependTo('.swipeySizeFilter');
  }

  $(function() {
    var swipeyScrollChecker = $('.swipeyWrapper');

    swipeyScrollChecker.scroll(function() {
      if (swipeyScrollChecker.scrollLeft() >
        (swipeyScrollChecker.width() -
          swipeyScrollChecker.width())) {
        $('.swipeyFilterOverlay').fadeOut(300);
      }
    });
  });

  if ($(".swipeyWrapper").prop('scrollWidth') === $(".swipeyWrapper").width()) {
    $('.swipeyFilterOverlay').hide();
  }
}

function swipeyFilterActiveItemsList() {
  $('.swipeyFilterLabel.swipeyFilterBtnActive').each(function() {
    $(this).prependTo($('.swipeyFilterActiveList'));
  });
  $(".swipeyFilterLabel.swipeyFilterBtnActive").sort(sort_li).appendTo('.swipeyFilterActiveList');

  function sort_li(a, b) {
    return ($(b).data('position')) < ($(a).data('position')) ? 1 : -1;
  }

  if ($('.swipeyFilterActiveList').length) {
    $('<div class="swipeyFilterTitle">TESTER REFINED STYLES <span class="swipeyFilterCounter"></span>:</div>').prependTo('.swipeySizeFilter');
  }

  function swipeyFilterActiveCount() {
    var swipeyActiveCountNumber = $('.swipeyFilterActiveList .swipeyFilterBtnActive').length;
    $(".swipeyFilterCounter").html('(' + swipeyActiveCountNumber + ')');
  }
  setTimeout(swipeyFilterActiveCount, 100);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('.selected').length >= 1) {
    swipeyFilterBtns();
    swipeyFilterClicky();
    swipeyFilterActiveItems();
    swipeyFilterSetup();
    swipeyFilterActiveItemsList();
  }
});
```

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 767px) {
  /* #Apple Device Scroll Fix
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
  * {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }
  .swipeySizeFilter {
    background: #f0f0f0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    padding-top: 12px;
    position: relative;
  }
  .swipeyWrapper {
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  }
  .swipeyContainer {
    font-size: 0;
    padding-left: 8px;
  }
  .swipeyFilterTitle {
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
  .swipeyFilterLabel {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
    margin-left: 12px;
    max-height: 38px;
    min-width: 38px;
    padding: 12px 8px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  .swipeyFilterBtnActive {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
  }
  .m-label-inline .swipeyFilterBtnActive {
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
  }
  .swipeyFilterBtnActive .swipeyLabelText:after {
    background: url('https://sb.monetate.net/img/1/422/2401995.png') no-repeat center;
    background-size: 10px;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 10px;
    margin-left: 12px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    position: relative;
    width: 10px;
  }
  .swipeyContainer>.swipeyFilterLabel:last-child {
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
  .swipeyFilterActiveList {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
  }
  .swipeyFilterActiveList:after {
    background: #000;
    content: '';
    height: 38px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 1px;
  }
  .swipeyWrapper::-webkit-scrollbar,
  .swipeyFilterActiveList:empty {
    display: none;
  }
  .swipeyFilterActiveList>.swipeyFilterLabel:last-child {
    margin-right: 14px;
  }
  .swipeyFilterOverlay {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(240, 240, 240, 0) 0%, rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.5) 10%, rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.85) 45%, rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.9) 85%);
    height: calc(100% - 2px);
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 1px;
    width: 20px;
    z-index: 2;
  }
}


/* #Default Style Overrides
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

.pagination {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.search-result-content {
  margin-top: 20px;
}


/* #iOS Devices
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

@supports (-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch) {
  body {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}


/* #Android Devices
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

@supports not (-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch) {
  .swipeyLabelText {
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-stuff"></div>
<div class="js-refinement-mobile-table m-refinement-wrapper m-overlay">
  <div class="m-refinement-header">
    Refine by
  </div>
  <div class="js-mobile-overlay-refinements m-refinement-inner m-overlay">
    <ul class="m-refinement-list">
      <li class="js-mobile-overlay-refinement m-refinement-item">
        <span class="js-mobile-overlay-refinement-title m-refinement-title">
     <span class="js-refinement-name">Size</span>
        </span>
        <ul class="hidden js-mobile-overlay-refinement-values m-refinement-category m-overlay">
          <div class="m-refinement-fixed-height">
            <li class="selected m-label-inline">
              <input class="js-refinement-link input-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="XS" name="XS" checked="checked" data-value="XS" title="Refine by Size: XS">
              <label for="XS">XS</label>
            </li>
            <li class="selected m-label-inline">
              <input class="js-refinement-link input-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="S" name="S" data-name="size" data-value="S" checked="checked" title="Refine by Size: S">
              <label for="S">S</label>
            </li>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="js-mobile-overlay-refinement m-refinement-item">
        <span class="js-mobile-overlay-refinement-title m-refinement-title">
     <span class="js-refinement-name">Colour</span>
        </span>
        <ul class="hidden js-mobile-overlay-refinement-values m-refinement-category m-overlay">
          <div class="m-refinement-fixed-height">
            <li class="selected swatch-beige m-label-inline">
              <input class="js-refinement-link input-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="Beige" name="Beige" checked="checked" data-value="Beige" title="Currently Refined by Colour: Beige">
              <label for="Beige">Beige</label>
            </li>
            <li class=" m-label-inline">
              <input class="js-refinement-link input-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="Black" name="Black" data-name="color" data-value="Black" title="Refine by Colour: Black">
              <label for="Black">Black</label>
            </li>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Apologies if I haven't explained this in the best way, but it might make more sense on my Codepen of this: https://codepen.io/nickelse/pen/dyyEqzR

Comment: Where in your JS code are you extracting the relevant titles? Maybe that's all the code that's relevant.

Comment: Please have a read of [mcve], especially the *minimal* part.  Narrow the code down to the bit that you're having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you

```
$('.input-checkbox').on('click', function(item){
    if(document.getElementById($(this).attr('id')).checked && !$('.swipeySizeFilter label#active-'+ $(this).attr('data-value')).length){

        $('.swipeySizeFilter').append('<label for="'+ $(this).attr('data-value') + '" id= "active-'+$(this).attr('data-value') + '" class="swipeyFilterLabel NickTester swipeyFilterBtnActive"><span class="swipeyLabelText">' + $(this).attr('data-value') +'</span></label>')

    }
})
```

And also don`t forget to add id to all pre-selected checkbox active-{id}

Answer (score 0):

```js
var filterItem = '.m-refinement-item',
  filterItemClick = filterItem + ' .js-button-apply';

function swipeyFilterBtns() {
  $(".content-stuff").before("<section class='swipeySizeFilter'></section>");

  var index = 1;
  var text_val = $('.m-refinement-item').find('.js-refinement-name').text();

  console.log(text_val);

  $(filterItem)
    .find('.selected label')
    .clone()
    .wrapInner('<span class="swipeyLabelText">' + text_val + ': </span>')
    .appendTo($('.swipeySizeFilter'));

  $('.swipeySizeFilter label').each(function() {
    $(this)
      .addClass('swipeyFilterLabel')
      .attr('data-position', index);
    index++;
  });
}

function swipeyFilterClicky() {
  $(".swipeyFilterLabel").click(
    function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(".js-overlay.js-mobile-overlay.m-refine-by-button").click();
        $(filterItemClick).click();
        $(".js-apply-refinements").click();
      }, 400);
    });
}

function swipeyFilterActiveItems() {
  $('.input-checkbox').on('change', function() {
    $(this).add('label[for="' + this.id + '"]').toggleClass('NickTester').toggleClass('swipeyFilterBtnActive', this.checked);
  }).trigger('change');
}

function swipeyFilterSetup() {
  var swipeyFilterCheck = $('.swipeyWrapper');

  if (swipeyFilterCheck.length === 0) {
    $('.swipeyFilterLabel').wrapAll('<div class="swipeyWrapper"><div class="swipeyContainer"></div></div>');
    $('<span class="swipeyFilterActiveList"></span>').prependTo('.swipeyContainer');
    $('<div class="swipeyFilterOverlay"></div>').prependTo('.swipeySizeFilter');
  }

  $(function() {
    var swipeyScrollChecker = $('.swipeyWrapper');

    swipeyScrollChecker.scroll(function() {
      if (swipeyScrollChecker.scrollLeft() >
        (swipeyScrollChecker.width() -
          swipeyScrollChecker.width())) {
        $('.swipeyFilterOverlay').fadeOut(300);
      }
    });
  });

  if ($(".swipeyWrapper").prop('scrollWidth') === $(".swipeyWrapper").width()) {
    $('.swipeyFilterOverlay').hide();
  }
}

function swipeyFilterActiveItemsList() {
  $('.swipeyFilterLabel.swipeyFilterBtnActive').each(function() {
    $(this).prependTo($('.swipeyFilterActiveList'));
  });
  $(".swipeyFilterLabel.swipeyFilterBtnActive").sort(sort_li).appendTo('.swipeyFilterActiveList');

  function sort_li(a, b) {
    return ($(b).data('position')) < ($(a).data('position')) ? 1 : -1;
  }

  if ($('.swipeyFilterActiveList').length) {
    $('<div class="swipeyFilterTitle">TESTER REFINED STYLES <span class="swipeyFilterCounter"></span>:</div>').prependTo('.swipeySizeFilter');
  }

  function swipeyFilterActiveCount() {
    var swipeyActiveCountNumber = $('.swipeyFilterActiveList .swipeyFilterBtnActive').length;
    $(".swipeyFilterCounter").html('(' + swipeyActiveCountNumber + ')');
  }
  setTimeout(swipeyFilterActiveCount, 100);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('.selected').length >= 1) {
    swipeyFilterBtns();
    swipeyFilterClicky();
    swipeyFilterActiveItems();
    swipeyFilterSetup();
    swipeyFilterActiveItemsList();
  }
});
```

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 767px) {
  /* #Apple Device Scroll Fix
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
  * {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }
  .swipeySizeFilter {
    background: #f0f0f0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    padding-top: 12px;
    position: relative;
  }
  .swipeyWrapper {
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  }
  .swipeyContainer {
    font-size: 0;
    padding-left: 8px;
  }
  .swipeyFilterTitle {
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
  .swipeyFilterLabel {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
    margin-left: 12px;
    max-height: 38px;
    min-width: 38px;
    padding: 12px 8px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  .swipeyFilterBtnActive {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
  }
  .m-label-inline .swipeyFilterBtnActive {
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
  }
  .swipeyFilterBtnActive .swipeyLabelText:after {
    background: url('https://sb.monetate.net/img/1/422/2401995.png') no-repeat center;
    background-size: 10px;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 10px;
    margin-left: 12px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    position: relative;
    width: 10px;
  }
  .swipeyContainer>.swipeyFilterLabel:last-child {
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
  .swipeyFilterActiveList {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
  }
  .swipeyFilterActiveList:after {
    background: #000;
    content: '';
    height: 38px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 1px;
  }
  .swipeyWrapper::-webkit-scrollbar,
  .swipeyFilterActiveList:empty {
    display: none;
  }
  .swipeyFilterActiveList>.swipeyFilterLabel:last-child {
    margin-right: 14px;
  }
  .swipeyFilterOverlay {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(240, 240, 240, 0) 0%, rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.5) 10%, rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.85) 45%, rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.9) 85%);
    height: calc(100% - 2px);
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 1px;
    width: 20px;
    z-index: 2;
  }
}


/* #Default Style Overrides
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

.pagination {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.search-result-content {
  margin-top: 20px;
}


/* #iOS Devices
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

@supports (-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch) {
  body {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}


/* #Android Devices
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

@supports not (-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch) {
  .swipeyLabelText {
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-stuff"></div>
<div class="js-refinement-mobile-table m-refinement-wrapper m-overlay">
  <div class="m-refinement-header">
    Refine by
  </div>
  <div class="js-mobile-overlay-refinements m-refinement-inner m-overlay">
    <ul class="m-refinement-list">
      <li class="js-mobile-overlay-refinement m-refinement-item">
        <span class="js-mobile-overlay-refinement-title m-refinement-title">
     <span class="js-refinement-name">Size</span>
        </span>
        <ul class="hidden js-mobile-overlay-refinement-values m-refinement-category m-overlay">
          <div class="m-refinement-fixed-height">
            <li class="selected m-label-inline">
              <input class="js-refinement-link input-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="XS" name="XS" checked="checked" data-value="XS" title="Refine by Size: XS">
              <label for="XS">XS</label>
            </li>
            <li class="selected m-label-inline">
              <input class="js-refinement-link input-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="S" name="S" data-name="size" data-value="S" checked="checked" title="Refine by Size: S">
              <label for="S">S</label>
            </li>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="js-mobile-overlay-refinement m-refinement-item">
        <span class="js-mobile-overlay-refinement-title m-refinement-title">
     <span class="js-refinement-name">Colour</span>
        </span>
        <ul class="hidden js-mobile-overlay-refinement-values m-refinement-category m-overlay">
          <div class="m-refinement-fixed-height">
            <li class="selected swatch-beige m-label-inline">
              <input class="js-refinement-link input-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="Beige" name="Beige" checked="checked" data-value="Beige" title="Currently Refined by Colour: Beige">
              <label for="Beige">Beige</label>
            </li>
            <li class=" m-label-inline">
              <input class="js-refinement-link input-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="Black" name="Black" data-name="color" data-value="Black" title="Refine by Colour: Black">
              <label for="Black">Black</label>
            </li>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please improve your answer by adding a textual description to it. This will help more than plain code.